# Can anyone help me in this dbms query?

Tags: join, subquery, rdbms

[image: Schema Diagram]The Question-

Write a query to display the name(s) of the students who have secured the maximum marks in each subject, ordered by subject name in ascending order. If there are multiple toppers, display their names in alphabetical order.
Display it as subject_name and student_name.
O/P: first column - subject_name
second column - student_name

My answer-

```
select su.subject_name,st.student_name from subject su,student st,mark m
where m.student_id = st.student_id and m.subject_id = su.subject_id
and m.value = (select max(value) from mark group by subject_id);
```

Error-

```
and m.value = (select max(value) from mark group by subject_id)                 
               *                                                                
ERROR at line 3:                                                                
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

What i know is I will have to make another subquery something like

```
and m.value =(select..... (select max(value) from mark group by subject_id));
```

But I am not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind got the answer, we will have to use IN operator and club value, subject_id as they are a set.

```sql
SELECT su.subject_name, st.student_name 
    FROM student s 
    JOIN mark m ON st.student_id = m.student_id 
    JOIN subject su ON m.subject_id = su.subject_id 
    WHERE (m.value, su.subject_id) IN (
        SELECT max(value), subject_id FROM mark GROUP BY subject_id
    )
    ORDER BY su.subject_name, st.student_name;
```